# How to set specific data from database in fields when launch through activity shortcut?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, android-manifest, shortcut

I am developing an android based note taking application with categories.I am  supposed to create notes shortcuts on home screen. When user click on the shortcut the relevant activity should be open and the specific data should be set in Edit-texts i.e Its title and description.I unable to understand the logic to do that.

I tried all possible solutions that come into my mind. I passed Id of note in shortcut intent but when it launch from shortcut the fields are still empty.
This is my snippet of code to create shortcut:

**Function to create shortcut:**

```
 private void createShortcutOfActivity() {

        Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                TextNotes.class);
        shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

        Intent addIntent = new Intent();
        addIntent
                .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, editTitle.getText().toString());
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
                Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);  //may it's already there so   don't duplicate
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
    }
```

This function is called when user click on option to create shortcut.

**In Menifest use permission:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

Also add intent filter and exported property in non launching activity:

```
<activity
            android:name=".TextNotes"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

The activity receive data from intent when open a note from another activity:

```
Intent newInt=getIntent();
        isDoubleClicked=newInt.getBooleanExtra("Chk",false);
        Cat=newInt.getStringExtra("Category");
        Id=newInt.getIntExtra("Id",0);

        String title=newInt.getStringExtra("Message");
        String description=newInt.getStringExtra("Message2");
        check=newInt.getStringExtra("Check");

        editTitle.setText(title);
        editText.setText(description);
```

I also tried to use this id in the shortcut intent of the function but having no change in result.

```
shortcutIntent.putExtra("key_primary",Id);
```

I want to keep the data when open using shortcut.For example for different note shortcut the rspected data should be set in fields just like in whatsapp the chat shortcuts of different contacts can be craeted . But unfortunately I am unable to understand that how should it be done because everytime I open using shortcut its fields become empty. Where should I pass id and how to set data when it launch from shortcut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `shortcutIntent.putExtra("key_primary",Id);` then you need to retrieve it using

```
Id=newInt.getIntExtra("key_primary",0);
```

That is the first parameter (key_primary) is the key that is used to identify the specific Intent Extra. Thus, the key value must match the key value used when putting the Intent Extra for a value (other than the default) to be retrieved.

As such coding `Id=newInt.getIntExtra("Id",0);` without using the matching/paired `shortcutIntent.putExtra("Id",Id);` will always result in 0 as the Intent Extra doesn't exist so the default value is returned.

Comment: I used getIntExtra in my activity but it still retrieving no data.

Comment: @RabiyaSadaqat From the code you showed you did not match the keys which is vital.

Comment: OK I got it. Its working fine now by matching keys finally  its retrieving data. Thanks! Its very helpful.

Comment: @RabiyaSadaqat, thatt's good. If the answer helped you to solve the issue, then please Tick the answer as having answered your question.